# XMPP stanza to tell client to log out

Tags: xmpp

I'm want to logout some clients from server, and I'm looking for a stanza or extension (if available) that will tell the client to logout.

I know I can kill the connection from the server side, but most clients have an auto-reconnect feature.

NOTE: I need to be able to use this with standard xmpp clients like pidgin, adium,etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send a packet to close stream:

```
</stream:stream>
```

Reference: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-close